# ag-Grid: How can I Unit test ICellRendererAngularComp

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have created a custom control which implements ICellRendererAngularComp from ag-grid with a set of actions and injected it into my ag-grid main component, but I'm not sure how can I write my tests for the custom control as to mock the `params` do we have any predefined class or module which needs to be imported

Following is my code block

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  template: ` <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
    title="Copy"
    (click)="triggerAction('copy')"
  >
    <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
  </button>`
})

export class GridButtonsComponent
  implements ICellRendererAngularComp
{
  public params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  public triggerAction(actionType: string) {
    this.params.data.actionType = actionType; // custom property added
    this.params.clicked(this.params.data);
  }
}
```

Following is the test that I tried

```
describe('GridButtonsComponent', () => {
  let component: GridButtonsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GridButtonsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [GridButtonsComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GridButtonsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let params = {
      column: 'status',
      value: 'test-value',
      data: {
        actionType: ''
      }
    };
    component.agInit(params);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return false for refresh', () => {
    expect(component.refresh()).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should actionType be as input passed', () => {
    component.triggerAction('edit');
    expect(component.params.data.actionType).toBe('edit');
  });
});
```

with the last test, I'm not sure how to mock `this.params.clicked(this.params.data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an additional mock function for `params`.

```
let params = {
  column: 'status',
  value: 'test-value',
  data: {
    actionType: ''
  },
  clicked: function () { }
};
```

And then assert whether the `clicked` function have been called or not in this way. Self explanatory..

```
it('should actionType be as input passed', () => {
  spyOn(params, 'clicked').and.callThrough();
  component.triggerAction('edit');
  expect(component.params.data.actionType).toBe('edit');
  expect(params.clicked).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params.data);
});
```